# Error when I try to print value of NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, json, dictionary

In my project I have a dictionary saved with NSUserDefault:

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @ "dictup"]];
```

Ok, if I print json dictionary i see:

```
    {
        company = Test;
        "id" = 32;
        lat = "45.0155447103";
        long = "9.7270244153";           
    }
```

This is a json that I have been downloaded previously, but if i try to print a dictionary value, i get an error. If I write:

```
NSLog(@"%@", json[@"company"]);
```

The application crash and i get this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSSingleObjectArrayI
>   objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x6040000119d0'

Any ideas?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. The unarchived object is an array. (*NSSingleObject**Array**I objectForKeyedSubscript:*)

Comment: @vadian yeah. I'm stupid. But I don't know how to print a single element

Comment: Arrays are subscripted by index: `json[0][@"company"]`

Comment: why the unarchived object is an array?

Comment: The error message says it's an array.

Comment: But when I saved the json file I have been printed `NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:jsonResponse];` 
              and  `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"dictup"];` 